# Infinite loop of form submit using jquery event

Tags: jquery, form-submit

The code is stuck in a loop when I try to catch a form submission. The purpose is to replace a value of the form before it goes out.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'convert.asp',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function(response){
         $('input[name="field1"]').val(response);
         $('form').submit();
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE: I originally had it bound to a button click event and it was working but I wanted to preserve the [enter] key element of the submit button. Seeing that the code is kind of illogical, would catching a keypress be a better idea?

Comment: So... you post the form via AJAX, and then `.submit()` it again? Why submit it twice? Just remove the second `$('form').submit()`.

Comment: @mblase75 `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @mblase75 is right here, there is no need for the inner submit. You've bound the submit event of the form to the function within so the second call calls the first again and so on.

Comment: @Christoph What about it? That doesn't stop the handler.

Comment: Do you want to change the form value before it is submitted or after? Because your code submits it via ajax and then in the success callback you change the input value. You are not changing anything _before_ here.

Comment: @mblase i know, but i guess that is what i think were greeners intentions... :-D

Comment: the AJAX is posting to a separate page than the form action (cross-domain)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I assume your ajax is an attempt to validate the form before its eventual submission. In that case just unbind the validation function before submitting the form.

```
  success: function(response){
     $('input[name="field1"]').val(response);
     // Add unbind to remove validations
     $('form').unbind().submit(); 
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! very clever :D
you do an unbind because it calls itslef on submit..
so if you unbind it it will not be called again :D

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the and .off() method is preferred over .unbind()

Comment: @firstTimeCaller Can you provide a code example with off()?

Comment: @bart $('form').off().submit();

Answer (score 8):

In the success you trigger another submit...

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // redundant,  you return false in the end. <<<===
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'convert.asp',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function(response){
         $('input[name="field1"]').val(response);
         $('form').submit(); // <=== delete this! <<<<=================
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You submit your form, prevent submission only to submit the form, which gets prevented to get submitted... :-D

Comment: Excellent comment, but not an answer... :-D

Comment: I liked it too! and I would upvote it, but only if it was a comment.