# Use of AJAX for form validation requires two clicks on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, preventdefault

I am using an AJAX call to validate an email field in a form. That is necessary because I need to verify if an email address is already taken.
After my first attempt caused an infinite loop of ajax requests, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812955/3559144) which seems to work fine.

Except: I need to click submit twice, before the form actually submits.
Does somebody have an idea why that is?

This is a minimal example of my js code:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/echo/json', {'mail': $('#test').val()}, function(data){
        //decide if valid or not based on data
        //we assume it's valid an want to submit the form now!
        $('form').unbind().submit();

        //we should only see this for a very short time
        $('.info').text('should have already submitted');
    }, 'json');
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lb6brje/1/).

EDIT:
Sorry, I think I wasn't very clear. I inserted some comments to clarify:
I want to use the response of the AJAX request to decide wether to submit the form or not and show an error if not. Not submitting works well, but if the mail-address is valid it takes two clicks on submit to actually submit. The example simulates that case.

The `unbind()` is necessary because otherwise I create an endless loop (`$('form').submit(...)` will be called again).
Also jQuery.post() is asynchronous so calling `event.preventDefault()` inside the success handler won't work because the form would have been submitted already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need?

Unbind `submit` event handler and then trigger `$('#submit')` click:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/echo/json', {'mail': $('#test').val()}, function(data){
        $('form').unbind('submit').find('#submit').trigger('click');
        $('.info').text('should have already submitted');
    }, 'json');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjyuqpou/)

---

Alternatively, use [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler (so that this handler fire only once), and then trigger `$('#submit')` click, so that the form is submitted in normal way after AJAX response.

```
$('form').one('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/echo/json/', {action : 'checkmail_action', mail : $('#test').val()}, function(data){
        //if(data == 'e-mail is valid'){
            $('#submit').trigger('click');
        //}
        $('.info').text('should have already submitted');
    }, 'json');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/npn4737j/)

Or, if you need to have the submit event again, you can wrap `.one()` event handler into a function:

```
function ajaxCheck(){
    $('form').one('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('/echo/json/', {action : 'checkmail_action', mail : $('#test').val()}, function(data){
            if(data == 'e-mail is valid'){
                // submit the form without AJAX:
                $('#submit').trigger('click');
            }else{
                // rebind submit handler, so that e-mail can be validated with AJAX again:
                ajaxCheck();
            }
            $('.info').text('should have already submitted');
        }, 'json');
    });
}
// bind single submit handler:
ajaxCheck();
```

PS. Don't use quotes on AJAX `data` keys.