# How do i stop submit form if validation failed in ajax callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i am trying to submit a form after validation using ajax. after ajax return if input field is valid then form should submit otherwise error message. below is my html

```
<form action="new-join.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return CheckForm()" id="NewJoinsub">

<!-- my form -->

<button type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large">Continue</button>
</form>
```

and ajax is

```
<script>
function CheckForm(e) {
    var checkpin=$("#JoiningPin").val();

     $.post("check-pin.php", { checkpin: checkpin }, 
     function(result){  
                //if the result is 1 submit  
                if(result == 1){  
                $('#NewJoinsub').submit()
              }else{  
                   var response_not = "<div style='color: #f30;'>Not A Valid Pin or Already Used</div>";
                    $('#pinCheck').html(response_not);  
                    e.preventDefault();
                }  
        });  
}(jQuery);
</script>
```

my form is validating correctly but its not preventing form submission if condition is failed. where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: can you try adding `async:false` option in your post call

Comment: Also make sure that your result is actually integer and not a json ( console.log(result) ). Since you are using jquery you can move also submit event inside script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="new-join.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="NewJoinsub">
  <!-- my form -->
  <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large">Continue</button>
</form>

<script>
$('#NewJoinsub').on('submit',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    var checkpin=$("#JoiningPin").val();

 $.post("check-pin.php", { checkpin: checkpin }, function(result){  
  //if the result is 1 submit  
  if(result == 1){  
   $(this).submit();
  }
    else {  
   var response_not = "<div style='color: #f30;'>Not A Valid Pin or Already Used</div>";
      $('#pinCheck').html(response_not);  
    }  
  });  
});
</script>
```

You have first to e.preventDefault(); !

To complete your example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="new-join.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="NewJoinsub" onsubmit="checkForm(event);">
  <!-- my form -->
  <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large">Continue</button>
</form>

<script>
  function checkForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var checkpin=$("#JoiningPin").val();

    $.post("check-pin.php", { checkpin: checkpin }, function(result){  
      //if the result is 1 submit  
      if(result == 1){  
        $(this).submit();
      }
      else {  
        var response_not = "<div style='color: #f30;'>Not A Valid Pin or Already Used</div>";
        $('#pinCheck').html(response_not);  
      }  
    });  
  }(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: its preventing submission on fail but also now its not submitting on valid

Comment: please check your "result". can you please insert console.log(result);

Comment: signup.php:88 Uncaught ReferenceError: CheckPin is not defined

Comment: with small changes i managed to make it work. First of all Thank you every one who helped me. i am against to down voting. i used $('#NewJoinsub').unbind().submit(); insisted of  $(this).submit(); . then its working. problem is its in infinity loop keep on submitting form again and again unbind stopped validating second time. ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812876/infinite-loop-of-form-submit-using-jquery-event

Answer (score 0):

I would of thought that putting in a `return false;` in your else like so:

```
else {  
   var response_not = "<div style='color: #f30;'>Not A Valid Pin or Already Used</div>";
   $('#pinCheck').html(response_not);  
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: not working form getting submit even using return false

Comment: That won't work because that is a callback function and not the function being called from the event handler.

Comment: is my html form is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: remove button type. Add click event on button and remove onsubmit of form. See the code below.

```
<form action="new-join.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="NewJoinsub">

<!-- my form -->

<button class="button btn btn-primary btn-large">Continue</button>
</form>



<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.button').click(CheckForm);
});


function CheckForm(e) {
    var checkpin=$("#JoiningPin").val();

     $.post("check-pin.php", { checkpin: checkpin }, 
     function(result){  
                //if the result is 1 submit  
                if(result == 1){  
                $('#NewJoinsub').submit()
              }else{  
                   var response_not = "<div style='color: #f30;'>Not A Valid Pin or Already Used</div>";
                    $('#pinCheck').html(response_not);  
                    e.preventDefault();
                }  
        });  
}(jQuery);
</script>
```